# Using R to combine long/lat data into UK region polygons

Tags: r

I've a CSV file with geoinfo:

```
JobSeekerId   LocationId    UpdatedDt   EndDt   Latitude    Longitude   Country      Name         JobTitle                                                    CompanyName       
559098           3042091    05:20.2     NULL    49.18804    -2.10491    GB   Saint Helier    Funds of Funds financial controller                       AXA Private Equity       
2949016          3042091    43:05.7     NULL    49.18804    -2.10491    GB   Saint Helier                     Investment Manager                     Lloyds Banking Group       
2093684          3042091    12:42.7     NULL    49.18804    -2.10491    GB   Saint Helier                     Head of Compliance              Bank Leumi (Jersey) Limited       
3397729          3042091    01:20.3     NULL    49.18804    -2.10491    GB   Saint Helier                         Trust Officer      Kleinwort Benson, Fiduciary Services   
.
.
.
```

Now, I have a UK shapefile, loaded using readOGR from regdal:

```
ds <- readOGR(datdir, layer = "european_region_region")
```

that gives

```
> ds@data
                          NAME  AREA_CODE        DESCRIPTIO                  FILE_NAME   NUMBER NUMBER0 POLYGON_ID UNIT_ID      CODE    HECTARES       AREA TYPE_CODE             DESCRIPT0     TYPE_COD0    DESCRIPT1
0          Eastern Euro Region        EUR   European Region        EASTERN_EURO_REGION        1       2     124430   41425 E15000006 1958623.344  45150.544        VA      CIVIL VOTING AREA          <NA>        <NA>
1    East Midlands Euro Region        EUR   European Region  EAST_MIDLANDS_EURO_REGION        1       2     124952   41423 E15000004 1581093.950  16766.722        VA      CIVIL VOTING AREA          <NA>        <NA>
2           London Euro Region        EUR   European Region         LONDON_EURO_REGION        1       2     124433   41428 E15000007  159469.727   2118.277        VA      CIVIL VOTING AREA          <NA>        <NA>
.
.
.
```

What I'd like to do is to generate a plot where I'd get the sum of entries in each geographical region/polygon: I'd like to get the number of users within the London region, for example. Is there a straightforward way of joining the data and the shapefile via the geo co-ordinates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those of the GIS site, I came up with the following solution:

```
library("raster")
require("rgdal") # requires sp, will use proj.4 if installed
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("plyr")



x <- getData('GADM', country='DEU', level=1)
class(x)
# [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"


# --------------------------CONVERT RANDOM POINTS TO SPATIAL POINTS DATAFRAME----

p <- DE_jobseekerdata[,5:6]

p <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = p[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")], data = data.frame(id=1:5013))
summary(p)

proj4string(p)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
x <- spTransform(x, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

proj4string(x)
# [1] " +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
proj4string(p)
# [1] " +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"

p<-spTransform(p, CRS(proj4string(x)))
identical(proj4string(p),proj4string(x))

library(GISTools)

# Polygon attributes at points
res <- over(p, x)
# Number of points within each "NAME" attribute
cnts <- data.frame(table(res$NAME_1))
names(cnts)[1] <- 'NAME_1'

# Join counts back to the polygons based on NAME
# Note that this will duplicate values
xFreq <- merge(x, cnts, by='NAME_1')
# Fill 0 where NA, these regions had no points overlapping
xFreq@data[is.na(xFreq@data$Freq),] <- 0
```

Basically, the solution makes a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of my input data, and I add a projection that needs to match that of the shapefile. It then uses over() to determine the number of counts per polygon and I can then merge the counts to the shapefile, and then plot etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned up version of Virg1975's answer to his question:

```
library(raster)
x <- getData('GADM', country='DEU', level=1)
# simulating some point data 
# to make this a self contained example
set.seed(0)
p <- as.data.frame(spsample(x, 200, 'random'))
colnames(p) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")
coordinates(p) <- ~ Longitude + Latitude
crs(p) <- crs(x)

res <- over(p, x)
# Number of points within each "NAME_1" attribute
cnts <- data.frame(table(res$NAME_1))
names(cnts)[1] <- 'NAME_1'

# Join counts back to the polygons based on NAME_1
xFreq <- merge(x, cnts, by='NAME_1')
# Fill 0 where NA, these regions had no points overlapping
xFreq$Freq[is.na(xFreq$Freq)] <- 0

spplot(xFreq, 'Freq')
```